# Using sockets with Flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I am currently hosting a tor website using Flask and stem. It has nothing special and is currently working.

```
import os
import shutil

from stem.control import Controller
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  return "Hello"


print(' * Connecting to tor')

with Controller.from_port() as controller:
  controller.authenticate()

  # All hidden services have a directory on disk. Lets put ours in tor's data
  # directory.

  hidden_service_dir = os.path.join(controller.get_conf('DataDirectory', '/tmp'), 'hello_world')

  # Create a hidden service where visitors of port 80 get redirected to local
  # port 5000 (this is where Flask runs by default).

  print(" * Creating our hidden service in %s" % hidden_service_dir)
  result = controller.create_hidden_service(hidden_service_dir, 80, target_port = 5000)

  # The hostname is only available when we can read the hidden service
  # directory. This requires us to be running with the same user as tor.

  if result.hostname:
    print(" * Our service is available at %s, press ctrl+c to quit" % result.hostname)
  else:
    print(" * Unable to determine our service's hostname, probably due to being unable to read the hidden service directory")

  try:
    app.run()
  finally:
    # Shut down the hidden service and clean it off disk. Note that you *don't*
    # want to delete the hidden service directory if you'd like to have this
    # same *.onion address in the future.

    print(" * Shutting down our hidden service")
    controller.remove_hidden_service(hidden_service_dir)
```

However, I want to do something but I have no idea how to do it. I want now to bind myself (the server) and the client with a kind of socket connection, so the site will not only answer requests, but will also be able to send some.

Do you think it's possible ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check out [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).